# Avoiding the use of USB connectors

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, usb

I have a question about avoiding to use USB connectors on PCB design. Is there any way to connect a USB device to a board using another kind of connector? I mean, using a cable with USB-C port by one side and other kind of connector by the other side. In this case, it would be 3.0 USB connection.

EDIT: The target of this is saving space on the PCB (or trying to.)

EDIT 2: I was asking for a solution like this:

https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32966866664.html

Using a FPC connected to a mini board where is the USB-C connector, and the other side of the PCB connected to my own board on a FPC receptacle.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sure they are. Some industrial embedded boards have this kind of connectors and flat cable to USB connector, but don't ask for the price.

Comment: Possible? Certainly. Is it a good idea? Usually not. A cable is much more fragile than your PCB, what happens if the cable fails? Also at the higher USB 3 speeds it might be challenging to respect all the requirements with a cable directly soldered to the PCB.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have editted the post solving some little questions. All this is about saving space on the PCB and the PCB receptacle, and It would be with 3.0 connections.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question, are you designing a host or device with a Type-C receptacle, and just want the receptacle to not be on board, or are you designing a device with a captive Type-C cable that ends with a plug ? What power will flow through VBUS (i.e. is device bus-powered) ? Do you need support for PD ?

Comment: @Nipo the USB-C side is connected to a camera, not to my PCB device. The device needs 0.7 A. I was asking for something like this: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32966866664.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The target of this is saving space on the PCB(or trying to do it).

You need to connect 7 conductors there (the two superspeed pairs, and classical USB1/2 signals and at least ground), probably 8. I don't think you'll get that any more compact than with a vertical USB-C connector.

Comment: But to use USB C you need to add device-host controllers, right? But, the USB cable connector (A or C) are too hard and huge, is it still the best option? Other doubt, What happens with the usb cable protections when you use other kind of connectors? Is it maybe a problem too?

Comment: seriously, vertical USB-C connectors are *tiny* for the 8 conductors they connect properly. USB-C itself here is just the shape of the connector and doesn't need any controller you wouldn't need anyway. I can't tell you what the "best" option is, as I can't look into your head and see all the requirements that you don't state in your question. Other question: please don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: The OP wants USB 3.0 and an C receptible. You require atleast 4 superspeed pairs (2*4=8) 1 classic pair (2), 2 Cabl configuration (CC) lines (2), and power/ground (2), this makes for a minium of 8+2+2+2=14 wires instad of the 7 you mentioned. Note that it is the responsibility of an device with an recetiple to read the CC wires and automatically select the 2 high speed pairs from the list, and send a signal to a mux to route the signals to your consumer

Comment: oh snap, you're right, @Ferrybig